# increment or decrement the values of an array

Tags: led, array, rgb-led

I wanted to simulate the Dawn light with my arduino Uno using array implementation.
I desired to change the brightness of the LEDs using fade effect( Smoothly and keep it unchanged until the next function called out) from 0 brightness to specific values in array ( it means specific brightness for each LED).
I wrote my code and compiled it but unfortunately nothing happens when I upload it to my device.
The device is already connected and I have tested some other on/off led codes.
Here is my pre-code:

```cpp
//Dawn Light Simulation
int LEDArray[] = {3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11};
int LedNum = 6;
int i;
int j;


int Dawn[] = {30, 20, 20, 20, 100, 0};

int Current[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
unsigned long time_for_fadestep;
#define Fade_Interval 1200;




void setup() {

  for (int i = 0; i < LedNum; i++)
    pinMode(LEDArray[i], OUTPUT);
  

}


void DawnMode()
{
  if (millis() > time_for_fadestep) {
    time_for_fadestep = millis() + Fade_Interval;
    for (int j = 0; j < LedNum; j++){
        if (Dawn[j] > Current[j]) Current[j++];
        if (Dawn[j] < Current[j]) Current[j--];
          analogWrite(LEDArray[j], Current[j]);


    }
  }
}
void loop() {
  DawnMode();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: I think you actually meant `Current[j]++` not `Current[j++]`, and the same with the `Current[j--]`

Comment: Also you should watch your method of delaying - you will fall afoul of the millis() integer wrap around problem. Instead you should be working with a past timestamp and a delay length (`if (millis() - last > delaytime)`) to combat it.

Comment: Hey Majenko,
Regarding of  ''Current[j++]'', I have made so many changes and got nothing in return,
relaed to your explanation about milis() , could you please explain more.....

Comment: Dear @Majenko ,here is a topic for my source to use milis() ,
[link](https://rudysarduinoprojects.wordpress.com/2019/02/21/fun-with-arduino-16-led-strip-fading/)

Comment: `time_for_fadestep` was never initialized!

Comment: Also you are using 5s delay but your `Fade_Interval` is 1.2second. Your first led will take 5*30=180s to get to the 30% brightness. Get rid of that delay.

Comment: @HadiMirdamadi That source is not good. You should use the official BlinkWithoutDelay example to base your time code on.

Comment: @HadiMirdamadi The second code with `micros()` has been done right. I don't know why he did the first one wrong.

Comment: @Fahad Actually, that's not true. `time_for_fadestep` is in the global scope, thus it gets placed in the BSS. The BSS is cleared during startup, so `time_for_fadestep` will always be initialized to 0. It's good for readability to be explicit though and assign it manually.

Comment: Hey Guys, The code has been executed fine, I made some updates with milis() and also could do the smooth transition between the array's values.... tnx for your comments